# Sharing selected text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a book-like application and it suppose to have an option of selecting some text and sharing it.

To make text selectable I use EditTexts instead of TextViews , but how can I share this part of text?

I know how to get this text as a String variable, my problem is that when you select text - you have a standart EditText dialog at the top of the screen that has options like "select all","copy" etc which completely hides Action Bar, so there is no way I can select text  and click "share" on ActionBar because it's hidden by this "copy-select all" panel.

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You could Override function "performLongClick".

Comment: What would it do to me? by longclick I can select text - that's what I need to do

Comment: You could override so that the contextual actionbar doesn't show